# How to allow Firefox 9 to open non-port 80 web site?

Tags: firefox

I searched some solutions, but rather old, don't seem to work with FF9.

Anybody knows a solution?

Comment: have you tried http://wwww.website.domain:port ?

Comment: yes, FF9 gave me two errors: - HTTP Error Status: 403 Forbidden; - Error Reason: Forbidden port

Comment: Sounds like a system configuration problem.  You should be able to view a website, provided there is a website on that port, on any port you indicate.

Comment: Do you connect through a proxy server?

Comment: @slhck I tried in two environments, one with proxy one without, I got same problem here. The one with proxy is a system proxy all my browsers IE/FF/Chrome use it and only FF does not work. Update, I disabled proxy in FF and it worked!!! Don't understand why IE and Chrome use same proxy still work.

Comment: Which port? 21? As far as I know there is no way to allow some low ports that can be abused via XHR like port 21. To override see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.security.ports.banned.override if you can accept the security risk...

Comment: @hardywang: If you found the solution, feel free to post it as an answer or when someone else was right feel free to accept his answer. If you post your own answer and accept it later on, you'll get reputation for it and people will be able to also give votes on your answer...

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 9 will allow you to append :portnumber to any domain, for example:

```
www.domain.com:1234
```

The error you mention in your comment is nothing to do with firefox, but is sent from the server itself as it won't let you connect on the port you are trying.

Comment: for example I visit http://server_host_name:81/ in IE/Chrome and it works fine. But got forbidden port with FF9.

Comment: I wonder if the server may be configured to deliver dynamic pages based on the browser identifier - and this may be mis-configured for clients connecting using FF9. That error message is server generated.

Comment: Sounds like proxy, I have IE/Chrome/FF use same system proxy but only FF does not like it other two just work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just add in `about:config` page a new value called

> network.security.ports.banned.override

and list the ports that you want to disable blocking on.

This works for FF12 and FF13 but I presume that it will solve your problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score -3):

Usually that means you need to portforward, as far as I'm aware, I used to host game servers, and the firewall installed on the router blocks access to certain ports (incoming and outgoing), there are instructions on how to unblock ports from a **huge** array of  routers [here](http://portforward.com/).

If you don't have a router, then you might need to call your ISP to unblock ports for you :)